# Can AutoMapper implicitly flatten this mapping?

Tags: automapper

I am trying to map between two lists of objects. The source type has a complex property of type `A`; the destination type is a flattened subset of type `A` plus an additional scalar property that is in the source type.

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Source
{
    public A MyA { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

If it's not clear, I'd like `Source.MyA.Name` to map to `Destination.Name` and `Source.SomeOtherValue` to map to `Destination.SomeOtherValue`.

In reality, type `A` has a dozen or so properties, about which 80% map over to properties of the same name in `Destination`. I can get things to work if I explicitly spell out the mappings in `CreateMap` like so:

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MyA.Name));
```

The downside here is I want to avoid having to add a `ForMember` line for each of `A`'s properties that need to get copied over to `Destination`. I was hoping I could do something like:

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MyA));
```

But if I try the above I get a runtime error when the mapping is registered: "Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type."

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

create mappings between `A` and `Destination`, and `Source` and `Destination`, and then use `AfterMap()` to use first mapping in second

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, Destination>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
      .AfterMap((s, d) => Mapper.Map<A, Destination>(s.MyA, d));
```

then use it like this:

```
var res = Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(new Source { SomeOtherValue = 7,  MyA = new A { Id = 1, Name = "SomeName" } });
```

Comment: A problem with this solution is Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() will fail.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use custom type converter with additional property in the destination type to avoid recursion.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MapComplexType
{
    [Test]
    public void Map()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<A, Destination>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ConvertUsing(new TypeConvertor());
        var source = new Source
                         {
                             MyA = new A
                                       {
                                           Name = "Name"
                                       },
                                       SomeOtherValue = 5
                         };
        var dest = new Destination();
        Mapper.Map(source, dest);
        Assert.AreEqual(dest.Name, "Name");
    }
}

public class TypeConvertor : ITypeConverter<Source, Destination>
{
    public Destination Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var destination = (Destination) context.DestinationValue;
        if (!((Destination)context.DestinationValue).IsMapped || destination == null)
        {
            destination = destination ?? new Destination();
            destination.IsMapped = true; // To avoid recursion
            Mapper.Map((Source)context.SourceValue, destination);
                            destination.IsMapped = false; // If you want to map the same object few times
        }
        Mapper.Map(((Source)context.SourceValue).MyA, destination);
        return (Destination)context.DestinationValue;
    }
}

public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Source
{
    public A MyA { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
    // Used only for mapping purposes
    internal bool IsMapped { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, Destination>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(destination => destination.Name, options => options.MapFrom(source => Mapper.Map<A, Destination>(source.MyA).Name));

var objSource = new Source { SomeOtherValue = 7, MyA = new A { Id = 1, Name = "SomeName" } };
var result = Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(objSource);
```

Comment: How is this answer different to the solution the question has in it? Doesn't your solution require multiple .ForMember calls from MyA which is what the question is trying to avoid?